# com.android.volley.error.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed, Only in Nougat device

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, android-volley

App is working properly in devices having os version below Nougat.
have given the certificate of the server (downloaded using firefox).

EXCEPTION CAUSE :

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0xabad5f00: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
03-03 20:54:52.507 12993-12993/com.mummysocial W/System.err:  error:10000410:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE  (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:610 0xaba93a80:0x00000001)
 03-03 20:54:52.507 12993-12993/com.mummysocial W/System.err:  error:1000009a:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO  (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_clnt.c:764 0xa7dc5912:0x00000000)
 03-03 20:54:52.507 12993-12993/com.mummysocial W/System.err:     at  com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
  03-03 20:54:52.507 12993-12993/com.mummysocial W/System.err:     at    com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java :357)
03-03 20:54:52.507 12993-12993/com.mummysocial W/System.err:            ... 17 more
 03-03 20:54:52.507 12993-12993/com.mummysocial W/System.err:   Caused by:  javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0xabad5f00:  Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
  03-03 20:54:52.508 12993-12993/com.mummysocial W/System.err:  error:1000043e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_INAPPROPRIATE_FALLBACK  (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:610 0xaba93a80:0x00000001)
  03-03 20:54:52.508 12993-12993/com.mummysocial W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
03-03 20:54:52.508 12993-12993/com.mummysocial W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
03-03 20:54:52.508 12993-12993/com.mummysocial W/System.err:        ... 17 more
03-03 20:54:52.508 12993-12993/com.mummysocial W/System.err: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0xabad5f00: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
03-03 20:54:52.508 12993-12993/com.mummysocial W/System.err: error:1000043e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_INAPPROPRIATE_FALLBACK (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:610 0xaba93a80:0x00000001)
03-03 20:54:52.508 12993-12993/com.mummysocial W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
03-03 20:54:52.508 12993-12993/com.mummysocial W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
03-03 20:54:52.508 12993-12993/com.mummysocial W/System.err:    ... 17 more
```

and followed this link from [Android developer site](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html)

```
 private SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory()
        throws CertificateException, KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    InputStream caInput = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ms); // this cert file stored in \app\src\main\res\raw folder path

    Certificate ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
    caInput.close();
    String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
    keyStore.load(null, null);
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

    String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
    tmf.init(keyStore);


    //TrustManager[] wrappedTrustManagers = getWrappedTrustManagers(tmf.getTrustManagers());

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

    return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
}

private HostnameVerifier getHostnameVerifier() {
    return new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

and created a varible of HurlStack and passing it to volley.init() method.

```
hurlStack = new HurlStack() {
        @Override
        protected HttpURLConnection createConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
            HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) super.createConnection(url);
            try {
                httpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory());
                httpsURLConnection.setHostnameVerifier(getHostnameVerifier());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return httpsURLConnection;
        }
    };
    MyVolley.init(this,hurlStack);
```

My init method looks something like this:

```
 public static void init(Context context, HurlStack hurlStack) {

    if(mRequestQueue==null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context,hurlStack);
    }
}
```

I downloaded the certificate using the firefox. and in firefox it's mentioned: this certificate has been verified for the ssl client certification and ssl server certification and inside `getSSLSOcketFactory()` method am passing `SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")` <-- dont know if it's due to this, (I tried changing this argument to "SSL", didn't work out.

Comment: Note that your `HostnameVerifier` may prevent your app from shipping on the Play Store and perhaps elsewhere. On Android 7.0+, you can set up a self-signed certificate via [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare i followed that link(network security configuration), still same issue.

Comment: @CommonsWare check edited question, i have edited with the cause of the exception :

Comment: Usually this means that the two sides cannot agree on a TLS version and encryption protocol.

Comment: how do i make them agree ? what's the solution ?

Comment: I have no idea how to do that with `HttpURLConnection`. OkHttp has specific hooks to help with SSL protocol negotiation.

Comment: i'll just have to migrate to retrofit i guess.

Comment: ^ migrating didn't help either.

Comment: @Bawa did you manage to find a solution? Im having the same problem. Please help

Comment: @mor222 - i had to asked the server guys to revert back changes to old version or something...it was a bug in a particular version of naugat.